# Project Outline

Tags: project-management-style, definition

I am writing a proposal for my project to create a data warehouse for a company. I came to the question of the Project Outline and I am a bit not sure of what shall I say in regards to this section! Does it mean a summary of the project itself?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where/Why did you "come to the question of the Project Outline"? The term "project outline" is not a recognized term of art.  What problem are you trying to solve?  Are you working from Organizational Project Asset guidelines?

Comment: This reads like you are looking for the work breakdown structure.

Comment: Or maybe a narrative description of the project's phases and phase gates? It's hard to tell from the lack of detail in the original question.

Comment: I think at the moment this question is unanswerable/unclear what you are asking. if you can clarify where the term "project outline" is used or in what context, it might be possible to answer.

Comment: Is this a template that you're using that has a section labeled "Project Outline"? If so, the place where you got the template from may have information/guidelines on how to fill in the information. If it's an internal document, do you have the ability to reference past proposals to see what other project managers did for this section?

Answer (score 0):

Project outline should consist of:

1: Business requirement
2. What is being proposed
3. Technology to be used
4. Timeline

This should give an idea if what you are going to talk about in subsequent slides.